# jquery to perform select on bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

Folks,
I am using bootstrap-datepicker,
Its a user driven form and when landed on datepicker page, I have difference choices for user to pick based on the date selected ( as you can see in data )
What I want is to let jquery to trigger click on today's date. It should be simple, but not sure why jquery does not perform .click on today's date. But if A user does manually click on date, everything works. Can someone please help.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
 });
    
var data = {
"2023-03-11":[
{
"choice":"Apples",
},
{
"choice":"Cherry",
}
],
"2023-03-12":[
{
"choice":"Bananas",
},
{
"choice":"Oranges",
}
],
"2023-03-13":[
{
"choice":"Pineapple",
},
{
"choice":"Grapes",
}
],
"2023-03-14":[
{
"choice":"Plum",
},
{
"choice":"Pear",
}
]
}
      $('#datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e) {
      
      $('#radioChoices').empty();
      
                var dateClick = e.format(0, "yyyy-mm-dd");
                var selected_data = data[dateClick];
                
      html = "";         
      for (let i = 0; i < selected_data.length; i++) {
      var d = selected_data[i]
      html = html + get_timeslot_div(d);


    }
    $('#radioChoices').append(html);
        });
      
      function get_timeslot_div(d) {
        return `<div>${d['choice']}</div>`
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-mSYUmp1HYZDFaVKK//63EcZq4iFWFjxSL+Z3T/aCt4IO9Cejm03q3NKKYN6pFQzY0SBOr8h+eCIAZHPXcpZaNw=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-T/tUfKSV1bihCnd+MxKD0Hm1uBBroVYBOYSk1knyvQ9VyZJpc/ALb4P0r6ubwVPSGB2GvjeoMAJJImBG12TiaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    
    
    
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
    <div class="card-body shadow">
      <div id="datepicker" data-date="2023-03-11" data-date-start-date="2023-03-11" data-date-end-date="2023-03-14" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="radio_time_slot" hidden>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8 ">
    <div id="radioChoices">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not quite sure about what you want,but if you want to execute an click event as soon as the datepicker is created you can use :

```js
$('td.active.day').trigger('click');

// right after the datepicker initialization
```